# Masked Autoencoder MADE implementation in TensorFlow vs Pytorch

Tags: autoregressive, tensorflow, density-estimation

I am following the course CS294-158 [[1](https://sites.google.com/view/berkeley-cs294-158-sp20/home)] and got stuck with the first exercise that requests to implement the MADE paper (see here [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03509)]). My implementation in TensorFlow [[3](https://github.com/marcelobacher/MADE)] achieves results that are less performant than the solutions implemented in PyTorch from the course (see here [[4](https://github.com/rll/deepul/blob/master/homeworks/solutions/hw1_solutions.ipynb)]). I have been modifying hyperparameters there and around, trying to identify the main differences in the loss-functions, dimensionalities, etc. to no avail. I would kindly like to ask for help in understanding what I am doing wrong, or what I could make better to improve the performance. Maybe someone could explain to me what makes the PyTorch implementation better since I have just lost it. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a difference in my implementation that makes the whole performance different: the random permutation of the attributes. According to the original paper, the permutation (order-agnostic training) should improve the performance in the density estimation, yet, I believe, if the training/testing compute an average over the permutations. I do not do any averaging. That downplayed the performance vs the PyTorch implementation...I believe this solves the question, but I leave it here for anyone who might want to throw a glance at my code. Thanks!